# Partial Message Serialize using Protocol buffer java api

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to serialize the below message partially i.e. I want to serialize first three properties id, name, companyName and don't want to serialize the age.

I am working Protocol Buffer Java API.

```
message Person{
required int32 id = 1;
required string name = 2;
optional string companyName = 3;
`optional int32 age = 3;`
```

}

can somebody help me on that?

Reetesh

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make a copy of the message, then remove `age` from the copy, then serialize:

```
person.toBuilder().clearAge().build().toByteArray()
```